# MySQL matching phone calls from two tables

Tags: mysql, match

I've been trying to solve an apparently simple problem for a couple of days now, and I can't seem to figure it out flawlessly, no matter which attempt I take.

I've two simple Tables, each with 3 cols: call_date, call_time, caller_id all of them are self-explanatory.

The first table contains inbound calls, the second one contains outbound calls.

After receiving an inbound call, the corresponding outbound call should be made within 30 minutes. So far so good, no problem here, but this is where it gets a little bit tricky:

1. There can be multiple inbound calls from the same caller_id in the inbound table.
2. Only calls that have a minimum of 30 Minutes distance to the previous relevant call are regarded as valid calls. So when someone calls four times, let's say at 08:00, at 08:15, at 08:31 and at 09:31, there are three valid calls: 08:00, 08:31 and 09:31. So after each valid call you have to wait 30 minutes again in order for the next call to be valid.
3. The outbound table can also contain none, one, or multiple calls to the same number, all of which must be matched as closely as possible to the incoming calls.

I tried various approaches to this problem, but all of them are not 100% accurately, always leaving one or more calls unmatched or not marked as valid etc, and my head is starting to spin a lil bit.

Right now I build a huge table from my inbound call table, adding numerous columns for the previous_calltime and next_calltime so I can calculate the minutes between the time stamps. A second approach I took, was to create seperate tables with the first and last calls each day of each number etc, but something always does not add up.

Here's a sample of my data tables, in- and outbound are the same.

```
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
| id | call_date | call_time|caller_id
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|  1 | 2013-06-01| 08:00    | 12345
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|  2 | 2013-06-01| 08:20    | 12345
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|  3 | 2013-06-01| 08:30    | 12345
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|  4 | 2013-06-01| 08:32    | 555-999
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
|  5 | 2013-06-01| 08:47    | 555-999
+----+-----------+----------+----------+
```

Maybe someone can point me in a rough direction which approach I should take.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

P.s. I am trying a 100% MySQL based approach here, but theoretically I could also make use of PHP, just in case someone thinks this is a pain to do in pure SQL and it could be much more easy using PHP.

Comment: Please add a table with your expected output for the given input.

Comment: @ Olaf H: The expected output is simply whether there has been an outbound call for each inbound call within 30 minutes. So you have 4 cols, the caller_id, the inbound time, the outbound time and the TIMEDIFF() between these two stamps.

Comment: @ Yve: I have just left my workplace, but I will post my code tomorrow morning, it's actually a PHP script, but it does only contain MySQL queries.

Comment: Can you alter the format of the tables? For example could you add a column to list whether it is a valid or invalid call?

Answer (score 0):

Initial code to play with.

This is ignoring dates (for now) but should give you a list of the valid calls. Not sure it will be that quick, but it might be an idea to use it to populate a list somewhere of valid calls (or to mark the inbound calls as valid or not).

Using you test data above it gives the results I would expect:-

```
SELECT Sub1.*, 
        @valid := if(@PrevCallerId != Sub1.caller_id OR (TIME_TO_SEC(call_time) - @PrevValidCall) >= 1800, "valid", "invalid") AS valid_call,
        @PrevValidCall := if(@valid = "valid", TIME_TO_SEC(Sub1.call_time), @PrevValidCall),
        @PrevCallerId := Sub1.caller_id
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Inbound
    ORDER BY caller_id
) Sub1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @PrevValidCall:= 0, @PrevCallerId := "", @valid := "") Sub2
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply and especially for the code suggestion. I've run the query against a test table that I put together at home, and it does the job except for some minor errors, where a call should be valid but is not. I made a screenshot of the output, sorted by caller_id and time. ![results](http://ubuntuone.com/3tPUDuP80BHEjaxQoyepiZ). Not sure if it comes up. I'm already seeing a pattern though, so I think I might work from there. And to answer your question about altering the table, that's a definitive yes, that's the approach I'm tried to take.

Comment: ETA: Okay I just had to ORDER BY caller_id ASC, call_time ASC to make it work. It works beautifully, at least with the little test data I manually inserted into the table, but it's looking really well so far. I have to admit this is rather advanced syntax compared to my humble mysql knowledge, but I understand what it does, and I just learned a lot. I will play with it a bit more and see where I can go from there in terms of matching. Reporting back when I've either figured it out, or need more support. Cheers.

Comment: Glad it helped. Sorry I missed the 2nd column for the sort.